# Shifting a result in 16-bit register

Tags: vhdl

I have a result in a 16-bit register which I have created. And after getting my result in this register, I am trying to shift it by two bits to the left. I am using the function for SLL to do the shifting but nothing is happening.
Here is my code below. NOTE: q is where the output of 16-bit register is stored in REG0.

If there is any other way to do the shifting of my result in 16 bit register please let me know.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;               -- Needed for shifts

entity L_shift is
    port ( a : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
           b : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
           clk, rst : in std_logic;
           --clr : in std_logic;
           --data_valid_in : in std_logic;
           q : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0);
           tst : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0) 
           --data_valid_out : out std_logic
    );
end L_shift;

architecture Behavioral of L_shift is
    component multi_8bit 
        Port ( a : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
               b : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
               p : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0));
    end component;

    component reg16 
        Port ( din : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0);
               clk,rst,load : in STD_LOGIC;
               dout : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0));
    end component;

    signal Bit8_multi_result : std_logic_vector (15 downto 0);
    signal load: std_logic;

begin
    --create  8 bit array multiplier 
    AM: multi_8bit port map (a,b, Bit8_multi_result);

    --create result register 
    REG0: reg16 port map (Bit8_multi_result, clk, rst,load, q);

    tst <= unsigned(q sll 2);
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Well, my VHDL times were some years ago, but is it possible to *read* from an `out` signal?

Comment: I hardly know Jack about designing computing machinery, but what do you mean when you say, "after getting my result in this register, I am trying to shift it?" Do you actually need to _change_ the contents of the register? or do you merely need to use its lower 14 bits as if they were the upper 16-bits of a word in some other place? What I'm getting at is, sometimes "shift" is a state machine step. But other times, "shift" is just a combinatorial output.

Answer (score 1):

What you try to do doesn't work in VHDL

`tst <= unsigned(q sll 2);`

`tst` is an `out` port of type `STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0)` and `q` is actually the same. As correctly stated in the comment, you cannot perform any action on an out-port that requires reading it, so `q sll 2` doesn't work.

So define an internal temporary signal e.g. `signal q_int : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0)`. Use this in the result register port map and to perform the left shift.

```
REG0: reg16 port map (Bit8_multi_result, clk, rst,load, q_int);
q <= q_int; --to still have the same result at q
tst <= q_int sll 2;
```

Note that the unsigned casting in the line with the `sll` is wrong as both types are `std_logic_vectors`.

**Edit**
As I've learned from the comments, reading from an output port is allowed since the VHDL2008 standard. So it should be sufficient to just correct the `unsigned` cast.

Comment: Wouldn't it be clearer to assign `tst <= q_int(13 downto 0) & "00";`?

Comment: Reading output ports is allowed since VHDL-2008. If OP enables VHDL-2008 support in simulator/synthesis tools, this should work, once the cast error is corrected.

Comment: user_007, thanks I somehow totally missed that, will update the answer. the busybee, I personally never use the integrated shift operations but I didn't want to alter the original code too much.